# Cosa vuol dire "mosceria" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, colloquial

Nel libro *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> «Figurati se quello torna! Sta così bene qua, tutti lo vogliono, tutti lo invitano, ha risolto il problema. Quest’anno ci vuole gente come lui, ci sta una **mosceria** in giro! Una volta, all’epoca che Dado girava col corvo e le scarpe incorporate nel calzone, c’era l’attrazione della mondanità, dei vestiti curiosi, della rivalità tra Dado e Rudy, tu te lo devi ricordare, parlo del ’46, ’47, ’48.

Ho cercato il termine "mosceria" su parecchi dizionari, ma l'ho trovato soltanto sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000992.jpg):

> **Moscerìa**, sf. Insignificanza, inconcludenza,
> inanità (di una situazione, di una circostanza)

Non l'ho trovato sul vocabolario Treccani, ma curiosamente appare sui [Sinonimi e Contrari](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiacca_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), come sinonimo di uso familiare di "fiacca, mancanza di forza". Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa nel contesto del brano sopra citato?

Comment: Direi che è il sostantivo astratto dell’aggettivo “moscio”, come “bellezza” di “bello”. Parola creata lì per lì, ma comprensibile.

Comment: Mi sembra che il senso citato da Treccani sia calzante. “C’è una fiacca in giro!”

Comment: Ah, OK, @Hachi. Forse il problema è che non conoscevo tutti i significati di ["fiacca"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000903.jpg). Quindi c'è troppa "svogliatezza", "pigrizia" in giro?

Comment: Sì, esatto, il senso è questo.

Comment: “Mosceria” lo sento dire a Roma come “mortorio”, per dire di una situazione noiosa, senza animazione, senza allegria. Però, non riesco a trovare una fonte.

Comment: Con lo stesso significato, in qualche posto potresti anche sentire _mosciume_. Questo lo trovi sul [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mosciume/).

Comment: Un'altra variante non riportata nei vocabolari è _mosciaggine_.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano:     Vedo che "mosciaggine" appare in questo [*Das herrlich Grosse Teutsch-Italiänische DICTIONARIUM*](https://books.google.es/books?id=GaWCWUaPJQQC&pg=PA560&dq=mosciaggine&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJh_vHravtAhUfDmMBHf-KCS8Q6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=mosciaggine&f=false) del 1702.

Answer (score 1):

Nel contesto vuol dire: "Non c'è vivacità, energia, senza gente come lui, c'è una tale apatia in giro!"

Ad esempio, tratto da
[Animali a sangue freddo di Stefania Amodio](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=3j8cAQAAIAAJ&dq=Animali%20a%20sangue%20freddo&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=mosceria):

> Ho abbandonato quell'apatia mentale e quella mosceria che m'impedivano
> di essere viva.